# non-ACID results with Apache Iceberg INSERT/MERGE

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-iceberg

I've read several places (including [here](https://blog.developer.adobe.com/high-throughput-ingestion-with-iceberg-ccf7877a413f)) that Apache Iceberg is not performant in highly concurrent write situations but I assume those "not performant" descriptions mean slow and not not-ACID.

The following pyspark program creates five threads that all use a MERGE to try and put a row into a table if the row does not exist for that same key value (I've tried a MERGE and a few different arrangements of INSERT... WHERE NOT).

Every possible combination always results in five rows in the table - instead of one.  I'm new to both spark and iceberg so this appears to violate the ACID claims of Iceberg.  So I assume there is some complexity in Spark/Hive/etc that I'm overlooking.

The below does throw lots of these types of warnings

> WARN Tasks: Retrying task after failure: Base metadata location 'file:/home/user/spark-warehouse/test.db/stop_duplicates/metadata/00003-e1aa06ba-2d18-4452-8524-3514fbcf2428.metadata.json' is not same as the current table metadata location 'file:/home/user/spark-warehouse/test.db/stop_duplicates/metadata/00004-a4c0cb49-5df1-4bea-8da9-1ca5f1d9716e.metadata.json' for test.stop_duplicates

But I assume that those are just the conflicts between the competing write processes.

How can I arrange things so that only one of these threads adds a row?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import InheritableThread
import time

conf = (
    SparkConf()
        .setAppName('scratch1')
        .setMaster("spark://localhost:7077")     
        .set('spark.executor.memory', '6g')            
        #packages
        .set('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12:1.4.2')
        #SQL Extensions
        .set('spark.sql.extensions', 'org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions')
        #Configuring Catalog
        .set('spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog', 'org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog')
        .set('spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type', 'hive')
        
        .set('spark.sql.catalog.local', 'org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog')
        .set('spark.sql.catalog.local.type', 'hive') 
        .set("spark.sql.catalog.local.uri","thrift://localhost:9083") 
        .set('spark.sql.defaultCatalog', 'local') 
        .set('spark.scheduler.mode', 'FAIR')

         .set('spark.hadoop.iceberg.hive.metadata-refresh-max-retries', '60')
         .set('spark.hadoop.iceberg.hive.lock-timeout-ms', '800000')
         .set('spark.hadoop.iceberg.hive.lock-creation-timeout-ms', '800000')
)

def runQuery(sc,query):
    df = sc.sql(query)

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
# spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

sql_qry = """
with cte as (select 123 as key, 'asdfasdfasdf' as words)
MERGE INTO test.stop_duplicates sd
USING (SELECT * FROM cte) src
ON sd.key = src.key
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
"""
sql_create = """create table if not exists test.stop_duplicates (key int, words string) using iceberg """
sql_drop = """drop table if exists test.stop_duplicates"""
sql_set_isolation = """ALTER TABLE test.stop_duplicates SET TBLPROPERTIES ('write.merge.isolation-level'='serializable')"""

runQuery(spark,sql_drop)
runQuery(spark,sql_create)
runQuery(spark,sql_set_isolation)


threads = []
now = time.time()
i = 0

while i < 5:
   t1 = InheritableThread(target=runQuery,args=(spark,sql_qry))
   threads.append(t1)
   i += 1

for t in threads:
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()

print(time.time() - now, " seconds")
```

[This](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration/#write-properties) documentation indicates that the default isolation level for MERGE is serializable (write.merge.isolation-level=serializable).  I've updated the code below to make that explicit but am still getting duplicates. I've also tried the snapshot option as that is better for high concurrency writer per [this](https://iceberg.apache.org/javadoc/0.11.0/index.html?org/apache/iceberg/IsolationLevel.html). Does this have to do with the local Hive configuration not being as ACID as Iceberg?

Comment: After further reading, it seems like the "Spark write option" isolation-level needs to be set to something besides the default of null per https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-configuration/#write-options

But how to do this in pyspark is unclear at this moment